# How do Trade Costs work in International Trade?

Tags: international-trade, international-economics

I'm currently reading a paper about trade costs in international trade, but I really struggle to understand the following passage:

> A rough estimate of the tax equivalent of “representative” trade costs for industrialized countries is 170 percent. This number breaks down as follows: 21 percent transportation costs, 44 percent border-related trade barriers, and 55 percent retail and wholesale distribution costs (2.7=1.21∗1.44∗1.55).

1. What does "tax equivalent of representative trade costs" mean?
2. "Trade costs for industrialized countries is 170 percent" of what?
3. How can trade costs exceed 100%?

Please help me out, I'm really loosing my sleep on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotation comes from James Anderson and Eric Van Wincoop "Trade Costs"  in the Journal of Economic Literature Vol. XLII (September 2004) pp. 691–75 and [a preprint of the article is available](http://www.bc.edu/content/dam/files/schools/cas_sites/economics/pdf/workingpapers/wp593.pdf)

The calculation is trying to find the equivalent to an *ad valorem* tax by which the price of manufacture increases by the time of retail sale.  Essentially it is saying transportation multiplies price by $1.21$ (a $21\%$ increase), tariff and non-tariff border related trade barriers multiply by $1.44$ (a $44\%$ increase), and retail and wholesale distribution costs multiply by $1.55$ (a $55\%$ increase) combining to multiply by $1.21\times 1.44\times 1.55=2.7$ (a $170\%$ increase).

This figure being over $100\%$ is not an issue.  For example you could imagine a high tax on a packet of bottle of perfume costing $\$10$ before tax: if the tax rate was $170\%$ *ad valorem* this would add $\$17$ tax and make the after-tax price $\$27$.

There are plenty of caveats: domestic commerce also faces retail and wholesale distribution costs as well as some transport costs.  Some goods see smaller costs, such as high-value low-weight goods seeing lower transport costs, or cross-border trade involving a short distance and a free-trade area, so this is in a sense a weighted average across goods and countries.

The article goes into considerable detail on the methods used for the calculations and possible implications for trade models.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Henry! So, basically these costs are calculated on the value of the good and then added to it, right? Are they considered a tax equivalent because the increased price would make the good less attractive to potential costumers?

Comment: It is an anology, but yes: higher extra costs make the traded goods less attractive to consumers, in a similar way to how a tax might